# Ionic basic plug ins(i.e.. pop up ) are not working in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, console.log, ngcordova, ionic-popup

I am new to ionic . I have written simple log statements 
like
**Console.log()** , **Alert()** and **$ionicPopup** . nothing is working in Xcode . The same things are working in Android .

My question is how to implement this in Xcode (Version - 7.3.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main Problem was  with plugging `Cordova.js` and `ngCordova.js` which was  giving me an error . And also Xcode is not showing error or exceptions in ionic code .  Also unable to debug ,  nothing can be traced . Now correcting my js files I am able to get alert , popups .